# RSS Feed for K2 Latest Items

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, rss

I have created a menu item "Latest items from (one or more) users or categories" using K2. I have set it to display the latest 1 item from selected users.

I want to create an RSS feed from this page - the menu allows me to create an RSS feed for each individual user, but I can't see how I can amend this to allow an RSS feed for all users shown on the page.

I have tried to edit /components/com_k2/views/itemlist/view.feed.php but this doesn't appear to be working as to how I need it.  Any ideas please?

*** Update ***

I have now found this file appears to need to be edited:

/components/com_k2/models/item.php

But I can't see how to show the author image or the author name in the feed.

According to Joomlaworks, the file which needs to be edited is /components/com_k2/views/*/view.feed.php but it doesn't appear to be working either!

Comment: Rather than update the question with the solution, could you please add an answer and accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not solved, otherwise I would have added an answer :)

Comment: ah...the statement of having found the file to edit was suggesting to me that you'd had your "aha" moment - sorry.